# Java Generic treeMap with comparator declaration without warning

Tags: java, generics

There is any way i can do next with out getting the yellow warning / @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Generics objects :

P=product to compare,C = custoumer

```
public static myComparator<Product<P>> comparator= new myComparator<Product<P>>();
```

comparator declaration is outside "insertIntoMap" method, 
i cant use the Product

object inside "insertIntoMap" method .

```
public static <P,C> TreeMap<P, C>  insertIntoMap(LinkedHashSet<P> set,C[] ac){

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TreeMap<P,C> treeMap = new TreeMap<P,C>((Comparator<? super P>) comparator);  

    int itrIndex=0;
    Iterator<P> itr = set.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            treeMap.put(itr.next(),   ac[itrIndex]);
            itrIndex++;
        }

    return (TreeMap<P, C>) treeMap;
}


public static class myComparator<E>  implements Comparator<Product<? super E>>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Product<? super E> o1, Product<? super E> o2) {
               if(o1.getName().length()>o2.getName().length())
                  return 1;
               else  return -1; 

    }
 }
```

Product Class :

```
public static class Product<E> implements Comparable<E>{

    private E serialNum;
    private String name;

    Product(E serialNum,String name){

        setSerialNum(serialNum);
        setName(name);
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result;
        result = prime * result + ((serialNum == null) ? 0 : serialNum.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Product<?> other = (Product<?>) obj;
        if (serialNum.equals(other.serialNum))return true;
        else return false;
    }



    public E getSerialNum() {
        return serialNum;
    }
    public void setSerialNum(E serialNum) {
        this.serialNum = serialNum;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return serialNum.toString()+": "+name;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(E o) {
       if(this.hashCode()>o.hashCode())return 1;
       else if(this.hashCode()<o.hashCode()) return -1;
       else return -1;
    }




}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is `comperator` and how is it declared?

Comment: It's hard to understand what are you trying to do. This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Please edit your code into something that compiles, otherwise it is very difficult to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The `TreeMap` needs a `Comparator<? super P>` whereas `comperator` is a `Comparator<Product<? super P>>`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes and i cant use Product inside the method .

Comment: I'm lost. To be honest I think you should close this question, and write a new one where you include the `Product` class.

Comment: It looks like the `Product` class should be `Product<P extends Product<P>>` but we need to see it.

Comment: posted Product class

Comment: @StavBodik I'm glad Banthar solved your problem, but please can you change your `compare` and `compareTo` methods. They have to return 0 sometimes!

Comment: hhh i know , the problem is that return 0 have no sense cuz if its 0 its means they are equals and if they are equals. . . treeMap will not add it any way , no duplicates . so i fixed it or 1 or -1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted it seems:

myComparator should not be generic:

```
public class myComperator implements Comparator<Product<?>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Product<?> o1, Product<?> o2) {
        if (o1.getName().length() > o2.getName().length())
            return 1;
        else if (o1.getName().length() < o2.getName().length())
            return -1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

insertIntoMap should only work for `P` extending `Product`. Otherwise you cannot use myComperator (which compares `Products`):

```
public static <P extends Product<?>, C> TreeMap<P, C> insertIntoMap(
        LinkedHashSet<P> set, C[] ac) {

    TreeMap<P, C> treeMap = new TreeMap<P, C>(new myComperator());

    int itrIndex = 0;
    Iterator<P> itr = set.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        treeMap.put(itr.next(), ac[itrIndex]);
        itrIndex++;
    }

    return treeMap;
}
```

Comment: I knew that hope you are correct , my lecturer going to apologize ^^  he wants me to use map with comparator to compare product without using the object "Product" inside the method .

Comment: You are not supposed to use `Product` in `insertIntoMap` or in `myComperator`? You can pass comparator as an argument to avoid the first one.

Comment: Amazing you are right , i passed it and its works . . . i hope that he wont say that i even cant pass it .. . cuz he said this methods gets only 2 parameters, Thanks you very very very much !!!